# Error "validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)" by Toutorial

Tags: javascript, android, sapui5

I'm new to javascript and android and I want to program a multi page app with SAPUI5. For this I found a tutorial:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/df86bfbeab0645e5b764ffa488ed57dc.html
which works fine, up to Walk through - Step 8. I have exactly the same source code in my project, but it doesn't work. I get following errors:

```
  E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
E/Zygote: v2
E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
E/AndroidProtocolHandler: Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/i18n/i18n_de_DE.properties
```

I know the first and the second, but I don't find information for the rest.

Does anybody know where they come from and how to solve it?

Answere:

I don't know what the problem actually was. I tried with the SDK-versions and get many many gradle errors. After I solved it, I used the code out of Step 7 an added only the yellow colored lines and delete what was to delete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Not related to `sapui`**

Don't know whether it will help others or not.

I've got this error when I was trying to open a **pdf file** in `webview` by using **google docs**.

I've changed

```
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

to

```
webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url);
```

and it worked.

Comment: I am already using this but getting the same error not frequently but sometimes randomly.

Answer (score 0):

The last error seems to occur because the file /android_asset/i18n/i18n_de_DE.properties is either not there or maybe locked?

Maybe you misspelled it?

The EGL_BAD_DISPLAY error could have something to do with the DPI. Maybe this link helps: 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2212632

Comment: I saw this already but it doesn't worked. I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601116/not-able-to-test-cordova-android-app-in-device-attached-via-usb but it creates many strange problem with gradle

Comment: You can download the source of the tutorial for step 8 here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.08/code

You could try to run the sample code  and work your way towards the error from there.

I know that you wrote, that you have the same source code but the i18n file has already a different name. Maybe it is easier to pinpoint the error if you use the tutorials code.

Comment: I had the same code and the same names. The file you mean, is part of an other project in this project. I don't know what the problem actually was. I tried with the SDK-versions and get many many gradle errors. I solve it. I used the code out of Step 7 an added only the yellow colored lines and delete what was to delete.

Comment: Beside of this, I have still these errors, but now it works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to load webview on Dialog. If I load webview on activity, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, some time pdf load or some time not.
try this solved my problem.

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    if(view.getContentHeight() == 0){
         view.reload();
    } else {
         pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

}