# White screen after load page in cordova android app - Android 5.1

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I have an **Android - Cordova Project**.

When `index.html` (main page) page is loaded, on **Android 5.1** (real phone) only shows a white screen.

When I minimize app by the phone's home button and go back again, using task manager, the page loads normally as expected.

I found a similar question, where someone argued about `WitheList` plugin which I added to my project.

Answers are likely about to make a delay using `setTimeout`, which I applied, with no success.

I have some local `css` and `js` files in `index.html`.

In `onDeviceReady.js` file, I call `load` method to set the html content for a `div`, add some click button functions and re-size some `div`s in `setTimeout` and an `addEventListener`.

What's the reason for this?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the application from a PC/Mac running Chrome Developer tools?  You may see something useful in the JS console log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waaaauuu!!!

I upgrade my `jquery` to [v2.2](https://jquery.com/download/) and my problem solved!. It is a new challenge and new experience.

I start debug with a real device with **Android 5.1.1** (Samsung S6) and see that there is an error: `validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)`
But after search I don't find any useful answer (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210443/error-validate-display255-error-3008-egl-bad-display-by-toutorial)).
I guessed that one or more `javascript` file(s) make this bug (white screen problem), so I remove all js files tags from `index.html` and add one by one.
Yes, my `jquery` file version cause problem. I upgrade it from v1.11 to v2.2.