# E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY) on Nexus 9 + Android 6

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, android-6.0-marshmallow, display

I'm porting an old big application in Cordova 3.4, from Eclipse to Android Studio because this application used a library that now has been updated in Android 6.

After some issues with build.gradle and settings.gradle, the App builds, runs and I can make the apk.
Every thing works fine on devices with Android 5.

With Android 6 on Nexus 9 the app crashes, with a white screen with this error:

```
E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
```

On Internet I've found few answers to this problem, I've tried to work on images resolution, but the problem is not solved.
The post [Error “validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)” by Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210443/error-validate-display255-error-3008-egl-bad-display-by-toutorial) does not work for me.

Comment: Have you got the solution. I am facing the issue and nothing got me any answer yet.

Comment: I see the same thing, what is your setting in the app? I wonder if its related to this setting,     <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"        android:required="true"/>

Answer (score 1):

In layout.xml,maybe u defined a GLSurfaceView or other View to put your image in.

Is it right?

So if u put the image to your whole screen, the error wouldn`t be occured.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer about this.

After API 21,you would get GL thread problem which not occured in API 19.

Use this code, it will run fine!

```
            XXX.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //ADD YOUR FUNCTION
            }});
```

Comment: Where do you place this?