# Showing Blank White Screen while starting ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework

My developed ionic app is working properly on android but after some time it suddenly stop working.
When I use `ionic run android` command it gives me a launch successful message but my android device app gets started and is stuck on a white screen.

When I checked a log I the get below information

```
08-24 16:16:42.571 17660-17797/com.ionicframework.myapp696374 E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
08-24 16:16:44.528 17660-17746/com.ionicframework.myapp696374 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9f0a070
08-24 16:46:27.005 17660-17746/com.ionicframework.myapp696374 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9f3a6f8
08-24 16:46:59.288 13342-13509/com.ionicframework.myapp696374 E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
08-24 16:47:00.684 13342-13469/com.ionicframework.myapp696374 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9e4a678
08-24 16:47:17.422 13342-13469/com.ionicframework.myapp696374 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9eb4180
08-24 16:47:19.654 13342-13469/com.ionicframework.myapp696374 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9e37e70
08-24 16:47:20.813 13342-13469/com.ionicframework.myapp696374 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xba05be60
08-24 16:47:21.822 13342-13469/com.ionicframework.myapp696374 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9e5cc68
08-24 16:47:22.620 13342-13469/com.ionicframework.myapp696374 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb9e1b6f0
08-24 16:47:23.517 13342-13469/com.ionicframework.myapp696374 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xba12ef88
08-24 16:47:24.438 13342-13469/com.ionicframework.myapp696374 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xba05cb20
08-24 16:47:28.872 13342-13469/com.ionicframework.myapp696374 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xba1515f8
```

please help me to solve the issue, i am new in ionic framework.

Comment: Use chrome to get the console in your device (at this url: chrome://inspect/#devices ). When you run the ionic app and all is blank means the ionic/angular crashed for some reason.

Comment: I used provided URL to get the console, no errors are present there but still I am getting white screen problem on the device.

Comment: Ok. maybe this can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210443/error-validate-display255-error-3008-egl-bad-display-by-toutorial

Comment: Thank you, but I checked that URL already.

Comment: You should probably try doing `ionic serve` first and see if the application loads on browser! if it does than something went wrong with your platform `android` Simply remove android platform `ionic rm platform android` and than add again!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned by @gianlucatursi get the console in your device and it help me a lot.
Actual issue was with ionic and bootstraps, there is a collusion happening when i am using the bootstraps with ionic framework.
Refer the specified URL specified below for further details.
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-twitters-bootstrap-css-framework-again/8269